# How to ask users to confirm/verify customer contact details

Tags: usability, terminology, confirmation

## Background

Our application holds data about customers, including their addresses and phone numbers. Our users are employees who need to find information about our customers.

The customer database is large and holds a lot of out-of-date information. This means users need to work out if contact details are likely to be correct, especially if there are multiple addresses or phone numbers. One way to do this is by looking at when an item was last updated; if it has been updated recently, there is a much higher chance that it is correct.

For instance, we currently show:

> Mobile number
>
> **07700 900000**
>
> Updated 3 weeks ago

This works well to highlight recency when a number has been changed, but doesn't offer a way to highlight if a number *hasn't changed* but has been found to be correct, for instance if a user calls a customer and finds the phone number listed on their account is working.

## The goal

We want users to be able to 'confirm' if they find a number or address to be correct so that the next user can be more confident in the data.

An ideal scenario would be:

Whilst talking on the phone to a customer, User A confirms the address we hold for them is correct. The next day, User B views the same customer's account and sees:

> Address
>
> **1 The Drive, Townsville, AB12 3CD**
>
> Marked as correct yesterday

We have considered the following options as action links which will sit next to the data items:

- **Mark as correct** — currently the lead candidate, though it's not front-loaded and feels a little clunky.
- **Mark as working** — same as above, in addition a 'working' address doesn't really make sense.
- **Report as working** — the word 'report' may give the indication it's a negative action
- **Confirm** — usually associated with confirming an action.
- **Verify** — implies some higher level of checking (e.g. that the phone number may have been verified to belong to the user, but this is not the case).

---

**Which of these options provides the clearest indication to the user what the outcome of clicking will be?**

**Is there another pattern that could achieve this in a clearer way?**

Comment: Since you already know, apparently, the date of last update per data element, why not have the agent just save the data again?

Comment: What do the employees who will use this interface think?

Answer (score 1):

You could flag the number as correct or as incorrect.

> 1 The Drive, Townsville, AB12 3CD
>
> Marked as correct yesterday

or

> 1 The Drive, Townsville, AB12 3CD
>
> Marked as incorrect yesterday

For the term I would use a single word:

1. **Confirmed**: This is confirmed by a user, but still not verified by you.
2. **Verified**: This was or wasn't confirmed before, but it is verified by you to be working.

I am not sure about the veracity of the information you obtain, but you might want to consider adding both Positive and Negative confirmations.